# npm version just major (No minor/patch part)

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

What does mean for npm version if only major is specified i.g `"@angular/core": "10"`.

I know :

`~` means match upto patch

`^` means match upto major

Which versions will be installed for below dependencies ==> 10.0.0 or above it as well

```
   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "10",
    "@angular/cdk": "10",
    "@angular/common": "10",
    "@angular/compiler": "10",
    "@angular/core": "10",
    "@angular/forms": "10",
    "@angular/localize": "10",        
  },
```

Comment: try it and see if it is what you were expecting. then share your findings

Comment: It's the same as specifying `^10.0.0`. Use the online [npm semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) to see for yourself. Essentially, `10` installs the latest/greatest version of `10.x.x` that is available in the npm registry. So given; `"@angular/animations": "10"`, it will result in `10.2.4` being installed because it's the latest/greatest version available in the following range; `>=10.0.0 <11.0.0` _(i.e. it's the latest version available that is greater than or equal to `10.0.0` and is less than `11.0.0`)_